# What index should increase performance of select query?

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

This is table structure:

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| visitor_hash | varchar(40)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| uri          | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ip_address   | char(15)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| last_visit   | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| visits       | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| object_app   | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| object_model | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| object_id    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| blocked      | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

This is request:

```
SELECT  `object_id`
    FROM  `visits_visit`
    WHERE  `object_model` = 'News'
    GROUP BY  `object_id`
    ORDER BY  COUNT( * ) DESC
    LIMIT  0, 3
```

Time for response is ~77,63 ms.

```
CREATE INDEX resource_model ON visits_visit (object_model(100));
```

After this request the time for response increased to ~150ms.

How to improve performance for this case? Thank you.

**UPDATED:**

Answering to Michal Komorowski.
This is explain before index:

```
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | visits_visit | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 142938 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And this is after index:

```
+----+-------------+--------------+------+----------------+----------------+---------+-------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type | possible_keys  | key            | key_len | ref   | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+----------------+----------------+---------+-------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | visits_visit | ref  | resource_model | resource_model | 303     | const | 64959 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+----------------+----------------+---------+-------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I don't know what gives me this information.

```
SELECT  `object_id`
    FROM  `visits_visit`
    WHERE  `object_model` = 'News'
    GROUP BY  `object_id`
    ORDER BY  COUNT( * ) DESC
    LIMIT  0, 3
```

78,85 ms before indexing and 365,59 ms after indexing.

Also i have index

```
CREATE INDEX resource ON visits_visit (object_app(100), object_model(100), object_id(100));
```

But i need this one, because in other select queries WHERE contains this three keys.

**UPDATE:**

I'm using django debug toolbar to test performance of requests.

**UPDATE:**

Query:

```
ANALYZE TABLE visits_visit;
```

Output:

```
+-----------------------------+---------+----------+-----------------------------+
| Table                       | Op      | Msg_type | Msg_text                    |
+-----------------------------+---------+----------+-----------------------------+
| **************.visits_visit | analyze | status   | Table is already up to date |
+-----------------------------+---------+----------+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**UPDATE:**

```
SHOW INDEXES FROM visits_visit;
```

Output:

```
+--------------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table        | Non_unique | Key_name              | Seq_in_index | Column_name  | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| visits_visit |          0 | PRIMARY               |            1 | id           | A         |      142938 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| visits_visit |          1 | visits_visit_0880babc |            1 | visitor_hash | A         |      142938 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| visits_visit |          1 | visits_visit_5325a746 |            1 | ip_address   | A         |      142938 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| visits_visit |          1 | resource              |            1 | object_app   | A         |           1 |      100 | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| visits_visit |          1 | resource              |            2 | object_model | A         |           3 |      100 | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| visits_visit |          1 | resource              |            3 | object_id    | A         |         959 |      100 | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+--------------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Comment: Did you check the execution plan before and after applying the index?

Comment: Thank you for answer, Michal Komorowski, i answered to you below.

Comment: Sandy, count of rows is less, than in second case, but second one spends more time for response. I don't understand why.

Comment: Did you try to run the query a few times? Is the result always about 150ms?

Comment: Yes, i tried it about 10 times, result is 120-400 ms in second case, 50-100 ms in first case.

Comment: Try to run _ANALYZE TABLE visits\_visit_ and then check results. You can also try _OPTIMIZE TABLE  visits\_visit_ but it can take much more time.

Comment: Thank you for help, i applyed this two commands and got minor changes.

Comment: Could you make a small experiment i.e. decrease considerably the length of an index by changing for example _object\_model(100)_ to _object\_model(10)_?

Comment: Done, minor changes.

Comment: https://webmonkeyuk.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/what-makes-a-good-mysql-index-part-2-cardinality/

Answer (score 0):

I was confused by misunderstanding of sql mechanisms, so i decided to create model Popular and save instances in it every 24 hours. Thanks to everyone, who tried to help.

Comment: Just check the no of rows examined before and after creating the index.

Comment: Thank you for answer, Sandy, what does mean examined?

Comment: The rows column indicates the number of rows MySQL believes it must examine to execute the query.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html

Comment: @vadimka You should post this details as the part of your question and not as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that although you have an index, MySQL doesn't know how to use it properly. It happens when information about data distribution (statistics) within a table are not up to date. In order to update them you should call `ANALYZE TABLE visits_visit` and then check results.

Comment: I'd did it and added it to question.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in your other question, Prefix indexes are virtually useless; don't use them except in rare circumstances.

Shrink the fields to reasonable lengths and you won't be tempted to use Prefix indexes.

The optimal index for that query is `INDEX(object_model, object_id)`.  Attempting to use `INDEX(object_model(##), ...)` will not get past `object_model` to anything after it.

If `object_model` is things like 'News', I suspect the other possible values are short, and perhaps there is a finite number of models.  For "short" change to some smaller `VARCHAR`.  For "finite", consider using `ENUM('News', 'Weather', 'Sports', ...)`.

As for why it took longer after indexing...

- Without the index, the Optimizer had no choice but to scan the entire table.  This is a simple linear scan.  It would read but not count any non-News rows.
- With the index, the Optimizer has the additional choice of using the index.  But, perhaps most rows are News?  Well, it would scan the index (nice), but for each News item in the index, it would have to look up the row to get `object_id` (not so nice).  It seems (from the timings) that the latter is less efficient.

By shrinking the declarations and using `INDEX(object_model, object_id)` (in this order), the query can be performed in the index.  Think of the index as a mini-table with just those two columns in it.  It is smaller.  It is ordered by model, so it only needs to scan the 'News' part.  The explain will show this "covering" by saying "Using index".

If all cases, the `GROUP BY` adds some overhead -- either keeping a hash of `object_id` in RAM or by saving intermediate results and sorting them.  Then the `ORDER BY` requires a sort (or a priority hash) before the `LIMIT` can apply.